# Повторы строк php

Tags: php

Есть код, который выводит цвета:

```
<?
$imgs = explode(';', $item_row['imgs']);
foreach ($imgs as $img_out) {
$color = explode('___', $img_out);
?>
<div class="pop-item-color-item" data-label="<? echo $color[1]; ?>"><? echo $color[1]; ?></div>
<? } ?>
```

Из базы я получаю полностью весь продукт. А цвет содержится в одном поле в формате: 
`ссылка на картинку___Цвет;ссылка на картинку___Цвет;ссылка на картинку___Цве`т

В итоге получаем:

```
Синий
Белый
Синий
Красный
Черный
```

Как вы видите, здесь два "Синий".
Как сделать, чтобы выводится только первый "Синий"?
Спасибо.

Comment: Примерно так: ``if ($color[1] уже напечатан) {pass;}``. Имплементировать ``уже напечатан`` можно разными способами.

Comment: Логику то я тоже понимаю. А "уже напечатан" — как он определять будет? Ну подскажите мне один из них, самый простой. Можно полный пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: Создайте массив и добавляйте туда каждый цвет. Перед печатью проверять цвет на наличие в массиве.

Comment: Как это сделать в коде, который я написал?

Comment: вы же из базы получаете массив цветов? вот и добавьте в sql-запрос группировку по соответствующему полю.

Comment: Из базы я получаю полностью весь продукт. А цвет содержится в одном поле в формате:
ссылка на картинку___Цвет;ссылка на картинку___Цвет;ссылка на картинку___Цвет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = [];

if (!in_array($color[1], $array)) {
    $array [] == $color[1]; // массив с цветами
    // добавляем только разные цвета
}
```